# No Google Play Store on Samsung Galaxy Ace S5830

Tags: google-play-store, 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-ace

I have a phone, Samsung Galaxy Ace S5830, with an Android version of 2.2.1 Froyo.

I do not have Google Play app on my phone. Can I install Google Play app with this specific Android version?  If not, how can I do it?

I just don't want to use the manufacturer's product. There must be a way.

Comment: No it is not duplicated question. Android versions are different.

Comment: But the problem remains the same. Some regions don't supply the Google Apps framework with the device, and if you wish to use the Play Store, you need to install a custom ROM and flash a GApps package.

Comment: I'm not sure: But was "Google Play" rolled out to pre-2.3 devices? I only have one device running with pre-2.3 (a tablet with 2.1), and it never got updated to "Play". Maybe the app is still named "Market" on the Ace as well?

Comment: I have not app named "Market"

Answer (score 0):

You can install a "minimal Google Play"

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1918484

Answer (score -1):

Update your phone to 2.3.4 gingerbread... officially by samsung